# I can not create a React project

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, yargs

I started learning React.js and when I type in the command line `npx create-react-app {name of project}` it starts downloading the dependencies but at the end I get an error with `yargs-parser` being a low level vulnerability, I've tried updating the package, deleting the project and creating one again, reinstalling node.js and still doesn't work, besides I've seen in all tutorials that in the initial setup after creating a react project I should have more folders than those that I have, cause I only have the folder: `node_modules` and the files: `package.json, package-lock.json`, no `public` folder and from `src` I have only the .json files I mentioned earlier, I would appreciate if somebody could help with this problem **:/** .

`npx create-react-app {project name}`outputs:

`found 1 low severity vulnerability run "npm audit fix" to fix them, or ""npm audit for details`

`npm audit` outputs:

Low             Prototype Pollution

Package         yargs-parser

Patched in      >=13.1.2 <14.0.0 || >=15.0.1 <16.0.0 || >=18.1.2

Dependency of   react-scripts

Path            react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > yargs > yargs-parse

More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1500

Comment: Have you tried it with different names for your project? There could be a conflict going on there.

Comment: `npx create-react-app` creates a new folder with the name you gave for the project, have you tried looking for that?

Comment: Yes, already tried with and without hyphen, upper case and lower case.

Comment: I find the folder, the problem is that there are missing folders inside like `src` and `public`

Comment: What does `npx -v` return?

Comment: And maybe add a screenshot of the exact error output of the `npx create-react-app {name of project}`

Comment: 6.14.5 and node version: 12.18.2

Comment: I can't post images but copied the error output

Comment: I don't think that vulnerability warning should be severe enough to cause your issues.
Try running it in a completely different folder, using a simpler project name, all lower case?

Comment: Tried it and still didn't work

Comment: What terminal are you running it in?

Comment: I used the terminal of windows, also tried on vscode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying reinstalling node, cleaning npm cache, deleting node folders on ProgramFiles, trying creating a project with `yarn create react-app` , the only thing that worked for me was to install nodejs for Windows x86.

OS: Windows 10 x64